# Issue binding space as leader with evil-mode and general mode

Tags: evil

I am currently trying to set up my config so that I can use evil-mode while also using the space key as a local leader for some command while mapping my keys with general.el package.

```
;; hide tool bar
(tool-bar-mode -1)

(setq-default tab-width 4)

;; add melpa
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)

(use-package evil
         :ensure t
         :config
         (progn
           (evil-mode 1)
           ;(use-package evil-leader
           ;     :ensure t
           ;     :config
           ;     (global-evil-leader-mode))
           (require 'evil-leader)
           (setq evil-default-cursor t)))

;; for providing wrappers for defining keybindings
(use-package general
         :ensure t)


;; for telling me which key does what
(use-package which-key
         :ensure t
         :config
         (progn
           (setq which-key-idle-delay 0.5)
           (which-key-mode +1)))

(general-define-key
 :state 'normal
 :prefix "SPC"
 "w/" 'split-window-right)
```

But when I run the config I get the following error

```
error: Key sequence SPC w / starts with non-prefix key SPC
```

I have tried unbinding the space key but even when I do so my keybinding doesn't work and the space key just works as it normally does in normal mode. What am I missing here, is it some kind of conflict between general and evil-leader or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get the wanted behaviour by using the following

```
(general-evil-define-key 'normal 'global
 :prefix "SPC"
 "w/" 'split-window-right)
```

Comment: Feel free to improve your answer like from where that you found the solution and accept it as answer!!